# Setting logger verbosity

Tags: c#, logging

Can anybody help me set the Logger verbosity?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.utilities.logger.verbosity(v=vs.100).aspx

```
logger.Verbosity = "Normal";
//doesn't work

logger.Verbosity = 1;
//doesn't work
```

Comment: You should just be able to type `logger.Verbosity = ` then press Ctrl-Space for Intellisense with the appropriate options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the [`LoggerVerbosity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.framework.loggerverbosity%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)-Enumeration:

```
using Microsoft.Build.Framework;

// ...
logger.Verbosity = LoggerVerbosity.Minimal; // For example (see link for more values).
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
logger.Verbosity = LoggerVerbosity.Normal
```

Answer (score 0):

To set `Normal` verbosity, you need:

```
logger.Verbosity = Microsoft.Build.Framework.LoggerVerbosity.Normal;
```